# getElementById totalupdate result show on js alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On the jQuery totalupdate plugin counting the values and I want to show result on js alert box for example:

```js
function updateTotal(){
    v1 = parseFloat($("#s1").val());
    v2 = parseFloat($("#s2").val());
    v3 = parseFloat($("#s3").val());
  $("#total").text(v1 + v2 + v3)
}

updateTotal()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
option> dropdown> value> selection>
    <option id="s1" value="2.5">A</option>
    <option id="s2" value="2.5">B</option>
    <option id="s3" value="2.5">C</option>
    
    <div id="total"></div>
```

and on the Html id="total" shows result but I want to show it on js alert box.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Im sorry for the issue so  i will edit and repost my question so thank you for your information.

Answer (score 0):

To alert your result, you can simply use `alert()` function of JavaScript. Here is an example.

```js
function updateTotal(){
    v1 = parseFloat($("#s1").val());
    v2 = parseFloat($("#s2").val());
    v3 = parseFloat($("#s3").val());
  $("#total").text(v1 + v2 + v3);
    alert(`Your total is ${v1 + v2 + v3}`);
}

updateTotal()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
option> dropdown> value> selection>
    <option id="s1" value="2.5">A</option>
    <option id="s2" value="2.5">B</option>
    <option id="s3" value="2.5">C</option>
    
    <div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: @AliCanArici hope this answer worked for you. can you mark it as answer :)